# How to print all the elements stored in the field current under "org" in json document in using golang?

Tags: json, dictionary, go, glide-golang

The updated json is as follows:

```
    {
     "phone":[
                {"home":"58878767"},
                {"mobile":"32453543"}
              ],
     "org": [
    {
        "current": {
            "org_dept": "Hr",
            "org_eptime": "1516354574432",
            "org_name": "Uejsjak",
            "org_title": "Hakosklaks"
        }
    },
    {
        "current": {
            "org_dept": "Accounts",
            "org_eptime": "1516354561184",
            "org_name": "Abcd",
            "org_title": "Hakahkshsjs"
        },
    {
        "past": {
            "org_dept": "Backend",
            "org_eptime": "15163545",
            "org_name": "Ab",
            "org_title": "Hakah"
        }
    }
    ]
    }
```

I am using the following code to print on the key and values:

```
    personMap := make(map[string][]map[string]string)

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(ii), &personMap)


    for key, value := range personMap {
    fmt.Println("index : ", key, " value : ", value){

     }
```

The output I am getting is:

```
    index: org value: [map["current":""],map["current":""]
```

How I can print every value of fields under field "current"?????

Now I am doing this:

```
    personMap := make(map[string][]struct{Current map[string]string})
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(ii), &personMap)
    for key, value := range personMap {
    fmt.Println("index : ", key, " value : ", value)

    }
```

The output I am getting is:

```
    index :  org  value :  [{map[org_dept:Hr org_eptime:1516354574432 org_name:Uejsjak org_title:Hakosklaks]} {map[org_dept:Accounts org_eptime:1516354561184 org_name:Abcd org_title:Hakahkshsjs]}]
    index :  phone  value :  [{map[]} {map[]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `phone` and `org` are completely different data structures, and you won't be able to cleanly deserialize both into a homogenous format like you've got in the example. The best option is to at least partially deserialize into a `struct`:

```
type data struct {
    Phone []map[string]string
    Org []map[string]map[string]string
}
```

This will at least deserialize all of the data, but it's still a bit messy; a slice of maps of maps is not a great data structure to work with. It's not clear from the question, but if any of the fields are fixed, you might want to codify those in types as well, for example:

```
type data struct {
    Phone []map[string]string
    Org []struct{
        Current map[string]string
    }
}
```

You can then deserialize to this type and use it much more easily:

```
var person data
json.Unmarshal([]byte(ii), &person)
fmt.Printf("%v", person.Phone)
fmt.Printf("%v", person.Org[0].Current)
```

Working playground example here: https://play.golang.org/p/5W-7RzPimZj

Note that I had to correct an error in the JSON, it is invalid due to a missing comma before `"org"`.

Comment: But it is not considering field name "current".I have type "past" also.I have modified the json.How to do on this???

Comment: Either use the first solution, or add a `Current` field to the second solution. The examples given in the answer should get you started, a complete implementation is up to you.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. There should be more than enough information here for you to make the minor customisations needed on your own.